# Auto calculation not happening for dynamic rows

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am adding rows dynamically with autofilled values from database. After adding it, it has to calculate total. Now it is calculating total only for 1st row. for 2nd row onwards it is not calculating anything. And also overall total is not happening.

Here is my code

html form

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th><input class='check_all' type='checkbox' onclick="select_all()" /></th>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Item ID</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>UOM</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Tax</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Discount</th>
    <th>Amount</th>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' class='case' /></td>
    <td><span id='snum'>1.</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="productcode_1" name="productcode[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="description_1" name="description[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="uom_1" name="uom[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control price" id="price_1" name="price[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control tax" id="tax_1" name="tax[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control quantity" id="quantity_1" name="quantity[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control discount" id="discount_1" name="discount[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control amount" id="amount_1" name="amount[]"></td>
    <td><button type="button" class='btn btn-danger delete'>-</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class='btn btn-success addmore'>+ </button></td>
  </tr>

  <tfoot>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th style="text-align:center;" class="total">0<b></b></th>
  </tfoot>

</table>
```

javascript

```js
$(".delete").on('click', function() {
  $('.case:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").remove();
  $('.check_all').prop("checked", false);
  check();
});
var i = $('table tr').length - 1;


$(".addmore").on('click', function() {
      count = $('table tr').length - 1;

      var data = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td><td><span id='snum" + i + "'>" + count + ".</span></td>";
      data += "<td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='productcode_" + i + "' name='productcode[]'/></td> <td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='description_" + i + "' name='description[]'/></td><td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='uom_" + i + "' name='uom[]'/></td><td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='price_" + i + "' name='price[]'/></td><td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='tax_" + i + "' name='tax[]'/></td><td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='quantity_" + i + "' name='quantity[]'/></td><td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='discount_" + i + "' name='discount[]'/></td><td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='amount_" + i + "' name='amount[]'/></td></tr>";
      $('table').append(data);
      row = i;

      $('#productcode_' + i).autocomplete({
          source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
              url: 'ajax.php',
              dataType: "json",
              method: 'post',
              data: {
                name_startsWith: request.term,
                type: 'items_table',
                row_num: row

              },

              success: function(data) {
                response($.map(data, function(item) {
                  var code = item.split("|");

                  return {
                    label: code[0],
                    value: code[0],
                    data: item

                  }
                }));
              }
            });
          },

          autoFocus: true,
          minLength: 0,
          select: function(event, ui) {
            var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
            id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
            id = id_arr.split("_            
              $('#description_' + id[1]).val(names[1]); $('#uom_' + id[1]).val(names[2]); $('#price_' + id[1]).val(names[3]); $('#tax' + id[1]).val(names[4]);
            }
          });


        i++;


      });

    function select_all() {
      $('input[class=case]:checkbox').each(function() {
        if ($('input[class=check_all]:checkbox:checked').length == 0) {
          $(this).prop("checked", false);
        } else {
          $(this).prop("checked", true);
        }
      });
    }
    $('body').delegate('.quantity,.price,.discount,.tax', 'keyup', function() {
        var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
        var qty = tr.find('.quantity').valr price = tr.find('.price').val tax = tr.find('.tax').val
        var dis = tr.find('.discount').valr amt = (qty * price) - (qty * price * dis) / 100;
        var tax1 = (amt) * (tax / 100);
        tr.find('.amount').val(tax1al();
        });

      function total() {
        var t = 0;
        $('.amount').each(function(i, e) {
          var amt = $(this).val() - 0;
          t += tax1;
        });
        $('.total').html(t);
      }

      function check() {
        obj = $('table tr').find('span');
        $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
          id = value.id;
          $('#' + id).html(key + 1);
        });
      }

      $('#productcode_1').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
          $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            dataType: "json",
            method: 'post',
            data: {
              name_startsWith: request.term,
              type: 'items_table',
              row_num: 1
            },
            success: function(data) {
              response($.map(data, function(item) {
                var code = item.split("|");
                return {
                  label: code[0],
                  value: code[0],
                  data: item
                }
              }));
            }
          });
        },
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 0,
        select: function(event, ui) {
          var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
          $('#description_1').val(names[1]);
          $('#uom_1').val(names[2]);
          $('#price_1').val(names[3]);
          $('#tax_1').val(names[4]);
        }
      });
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
require_once '../connect.php';
if($_POST['type'] == 'items_table'){
    $row_num = $_POST['row_num'];
    $name = $_POST['name_startsWith'];
    $query = "SELECT items.iid, items.description, items.uom, items.selling_price, items.tax_id, taxes.tax_id, taxes.name, taxes.rate FROM items INNER JOIN taxes ON items.tax_id=taxes.tax_id where items.iid LIKE '".strtoupper($name)."%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $name = $row['iid'].'|'.$row['description'].'|'.$row['uom'].'|'.$row['selling_price'].'|'.$row['rate'].'|'.$row_num;

        array_push($data, $name);    
    }    
    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

Only 1st row total is getting calculated. Not getting what is wrong

Comment: What's in the javascript console if you hit F12?

Comment: `$('body').on('keyup', '.quantity,.price,.discount,.tax', function() {`

Comment: @mkaatman: When i hit f12 i get this **If <script> tags have a "type" attribute, it should equal "text/javascript" or "application/javascript". Also scripts must be parsable (syntactically correct).**

Comment: @mplungjan: Ididn't work :(

Comment: What does that mean? Console errors???

Comment: No errors, it shows blank

Comment: For this line, what is valr?    var qty = tr.find('.quantity').valr price = tr.find('.price').val tax = tr.find('.tax').val

Comment: Also, you set var amt in your total function and then don't use it. Why are you setting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it resolved.Because of the class i have used

```
  $('body').on('change', '.quantity,.price,.discount,.tax', function() {
    var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
    var qty = tr.find('.quantity').val();
    var price = tr.find('.price').val();
    var tax = tr.find('.tax').val();
    var dis = tr.find('.discount').val();

    var amt = (qty * price) - (qty * price * dis) / 100;

    var tax1 = (amt * (tax / 100));
    //alert(tax1);
    tr.find('.tamount').val(tax1);
    ttotal();
    tr.find('.amount').val(amt);
    total();
  });

  function total() {
    var t = 0;
    $('.amount').each(function(i, e) {
      var amt = $(this).val() - 0;
      t += amt;
    });
    $('.total').html(t);
  }
  function ttotal() {
    var tt = 0;
    $('.tamount').each(function(i, e) {
      var tax = $(this).val() - 0;
      tt += tax;
    });
    $('.ttotal').html(tt);
  }

  function check() {
    obj = $('table tr').find('span');
    $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
      id = value.id;
      $('#' + id).html(key + 1);
    });
  }
```