# Passing db values and display dropdown in script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is the related thread of [Auto calculation not happening for dynamic rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44005590/auto-calculation-not-happening-for-dynamic-rows)

I wan to display dropdown for `tax`. I am doing like this

```
<td><select name="tax[]" class="form-control tax" id="tax_1">
                                <option value="">Select Tax</option>
                                <?php $s1 = mysqli_query($con, "select * from taxes"); $options .= ''; while($s2 = mysqli_fetch_array($s1)) { 
                                $options = "<option value='". $s2['rate'] . "'>" .$s2['name'] . "</option>";   
                                echo $options;
                                } ?> 
                                </select>
                               </td>
```

In script

```
    var options = $('.tax').select();

  var data = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td><td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='productcode_" + i + "' name='productcode[]'/></td> <td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='description_" + i + "' name='description[]'/></td><td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='uom_" + i + "' name='uom[]'/></td><td><input class='form-control price' type='text' id='price_" + i + "' name='price[]'/></td><td><select class='form-control tax' id='tax_" + i + "' name='tax[]'><option value=''>Select Tax</option>options</select></td><td><input class='form-control quantity' type='text' id='quantity_" + i + "' name='quantity[]'/></td><td><input class='form-control discount' type='text' id='discount_" + i + "' name='discount[]'/></td><td><input class='form-control amount' type='text' id='amount_" + i + "' name='amount[]'/></td><td><input class='form-control tamount' type='text' id='tamount_" + i + "' name='tamount[]'/></td></tr>";
```

But from 2nd row, data is not getting displayed for tax. I am not getting how to display `$options` in javascript.

I tried doing alert like this `alert('<?= $options; ?>');` and `alert('php echo $options; ?>');` but it displays as it is instead of values.

Can somebody suggest me where i am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand what your `options` variable needs to be ... Can you exmplain a bit more please?

Comment: `options` variables will contain the dropdown values. There only i am getting confused. how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try following: And also let me know what you are thinking to do with those javascript. For simply displaying data in dropdown PHP works enough.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("database_name");
$sql="select * from taxes";
$rs=mysql_query($sql);
$tax=array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
    $tax[] = $row;

}
    ?>

    <select class="form-control" name="tax" id="tax">
        <?php
        foreach ($tax as $k => $v) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $v->rate; ?>"><?php echo $v->name ?> </option>
                <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Please refer [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44005590/auto-calculation-not-happening-for-dynamic-rows[/link]

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax to get data to display in options. I am not writing the ajax call but only the success function to display the select options.

```
    $.each(opts, function(i, d) {

    $('#tax').append('<option value="' + d.rate + '">' + d.name + '</option>';
   });
```

Hope it helps.