# Auto calculate product total price for dynamical rows

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I am continuing the same post i have raised few months back but i got the resolved There total is displaying in   or any cell which contains class total. 
Here is the link of the previous resolved post
[Auto calculation not happening for dynamic rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44005590/auto-calculation-not-happening-for-dynamic-rows)
But now i want to replace the total with textbox like this

```
<input type="text" id="total" name="total" class="total form-control" />
```

But when i change this to textbox, it doesn't show any result.

After the total displays, user will enter paying amount, then in last row i have to display the difference of total and paying amount. For that i have created 2 textboxes

```
<input type="text" id="advanced" name="advance" class="advanced form-control" />
    <input type="text" id="due" name="due" class="due form-control" />
```

And i have changed the script like this, in total() function i have replaced `$('.total').html(t)` with `tr.find('.total').val(t);`

Can somebody help me where i am doing wrong
**UPDATED**

```
function total() {
    var t = 0;
    $('.amount').each(function(i, e) {
      var amt = $(this).val() - 0;
      t += amt;
      //tr.find('.total').val(t);

    });


     $(".total").val(t);

  }
```

Comment: i have used `class="total form-control"` already.

Comment: Post your jQuery code which is doing the totalling.

Comment: I have changed the code and got total in textbox , but not getting how to calculate due when i enter advance. I have updated total() function above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate due using a jquery function. I have assumed an input for total.

```
    <input type="text" id="total" name="total" class="form-control total"  value="5600"/>

    <input type="text" id="advanced" name="advance" class="advanced form-control" onchange="adjustAdvance();"/>
    <input type="text" id="due" name="due" class="due form-control" />

        function total() {
        var t = 0;
        $('.amount').each(function(i, e) {
          var amt = $(this).val() - 0;
          t += amt;
          //tr.find('.total').val(t);

        });


         $(".total").val(t);

      }      

    function adjustAdvance() {
        var total = $(".total").val();
        var advanced = $("#advanced").val();

        console.log(total + "  " + advanced);

        var due = parseFloat(total) - parseFloat(advanced);

        $("#due").val(due);

    }
```